# subset of no-5 multiples

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

a naive approach is to take out all 5 multiples which has 100 of them - but it's wrong. What cases would save more numbers than taking out the 5 multiples? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Note that you have taken out $5, 25,\ $and $125$, so you can afford to put $25$ back in.

Comment: did even thought of that

Comment: There are others you can add back in as well.  It would be more interesting if the upper limit were $1000$ instead of $500$